# Comparing and updating CSV files using lists

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing something that will take two CSV's: #1 is a list of email's with # received for each, #2 is a catalog of every email addr on record, with a # of received emails per reporting period with date annotated at top of column.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%m-%d')
storedEmails = []
newEmails = []
sortedList = []
holderList = []

with open('working.csv', 'r') as newLines, open('archive.csv', 'r') as oldLines:   #readers to make lists
    f1 = csv.reader(newLines, delimiter=',')
    f2 = csv.reader(oldLines, delimiter=',')

    print ('Processing new data...')
    for row in f2:
        storedEmails.append(list(row))                                   #add archived data to a list
    storedEmails[0].append(datestring)                                   #append header row with new date column
    for col in f1:
        if col[1] == 'email' and col[2] == 'To Address':                 #new list containing new email data
            newEmails.append(list(col))
    counter = len(newEmails)
    n = len(storedEmails[0])                                             #using header row len to fill zeros if no email received
    print(storedEmails[0])
    print (n)
    print ('Updating email lists and tallies, this could take a minute...')

with open ('archive.csv', 'w', newline='') as toWrite:                   #writer to overwrite old csv
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite, delimiter=',')
    for i in newEmails:
        del i[:3]                   #strip useless identifiers from data
        if int(i[1]) > 30:          #only keep emails with sufficient traffic
            sortedList.append(i)    #add these emails to new sorted list
    for i in storedEmails:
        for entry in sortedList:    #compare stored emails with the new emails, on match append row with new # of emails
            if i[0] == entry[0]:
                i.append(entry[1])
                counter -=1
            else:
                holderList.append(entry)    #if no match, it is a new email that meets criteria to land itself on the list
        break                               #break inner loop after iteration of outer email, to move to next email and avoid multiple entries
    storedEmails = storedEmails + holderList    #combine lists for archived csv rewrite
    for i in storedEmails:
         if len(i) < n:
             i.append('0')                      #if email on list but didnt have any activity this period, append with 0 to keep records intact
         writer.writerow(i)

    print('SortedList', sortedList)
    print (len(sortedList))
    print('storedEmails', storedEmails)
    print(len(storedEmails))
    print('holderList',holderList)
    print(len(holderList))

    print ('There are', counter, 'new emails being added to the list.')

    print ('All done!')
```

CSV's will look similar to this.

working.csv:

```
1,asdf@email.com,'to address',31
2,fsda@email.com,'to address',19
3,zxcv@email.com,'to address',117
4,qwer@gmail.com,'to address',92
5,uiop@fmail.com,'to address',11
```

archive.csv:

```
date,01-sep
asdf@email.com,154
fsda@email.com,128
qwer@gmail.com,77
ffff@xmail.com,63
```

What I want after processing is:

```
date,01-sep,27-sep
asdf@email.com,154,31
fsda@email.com,128,19
qwer@gmail.com,77,92
ffff@xmail.com,63,0
zxcv@email.com,0,117
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong at - but it keeps producing duplicate entries. Some of the functionality is there but I've been at it for too long and I'm getting tunnel vision trying to figure out what I have done wrong with my loops.

I know my zero-filler section in the end is wrong as well, as it will append onto the end of a newly created record instead of populating zero's up to its first appearance.

I'm sure there are far more efficient ways to do this, I'm new to programming so its probably overly complicated and messy - initially I tried to compare CSV to CSV and realized that wasnt possible since you cant read and write at the same time, so I attempted to convert to using lists, which I also know wont work forever due to memory limitations when the list gets big.

-EDIT-
Using Trenton's Panda's solution:

I ran a script on working.csv so it instead produces the following:

```
asdf@email.com,1000
bsdf@gmail.com,500
xyz@fmail.com,9999
```

I have modified your solution to reflect this change:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv

# get the date string
datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d-%b')

# filter original list to grab only emails of interest
with open ('working.csv', 'r') as fr, open ('writer.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == 'Email' and row[2] == 'To Address':
            writer.writerow([row[3], row[4]])

# read archive
arch = pd.read_csv('archive.csv')

# rename columns
arch.rename(columns={'email': 'date'}, inplace=True)

# read working, but only the two columns that are needed
working = pd.read_csv('writer.csv', header=None, usecols=[0, 1]) # I assume usecols isnt necessery anymore, but I'm not sure

# rename columns
working.rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: datestring}, inplace=True)

# only emails greater than 30 or already in arch
working = working[(working[datestring] > 30) | (working.email.isin(arch.email))]

# merge
arch_updated = pd.merge(arch, working, on='email', how='outer').fillna(0)

# save to csv
arch_updated.to_csv('archive.csv', index=False)
```

I apparently still have no idea how this works because I'm now getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---/agsdga.py", line 29, in <module>
    working = working[(working[datestring] > 30) | (working.email.isin(arch.email))]
  File "---\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5130, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'email'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

-UPDATE-
It is working now as:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv

# get the date string
datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d-%b')

with open ('working.csv', 'r') as fr, open ('writer.csv', 'w', newline='') as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == 'Email' and row[2] == 'To Address':

            writer.writerow([row[3], row[4]])

# read archive
arch = pd.read_csv('archive.csv')

# rename columns
arch.rename(columns={'date': 'email'}, inplace=True)

# read working, but only the two columns that are needed
working = pd.read_csv('writer.csv', header=None, usecols=[0, 1])

# rename columns
working.rename(columns={0: 'email', 1: datestring}, inplace=True)

# only emails greater than 30 or already in arch
working = working[(working[datestring] > 30) | (working.email.isin(arch.email))]

# merge
arch_updated = pd.merge(arch, working, on='email', how='outer').fillna(0)

# save to csv
arch_updated.to_csv('archive.csv', index=False)
```

The errors above were caused because I changed

```
arch.rename(columns={'date': 'email'}, inplace=True)
```

to

```
arch.rename(columns={'email': 'date'}, inplace=True)
```

I ran into further complications because I stripped the header row from the test archive because I didnt think the header mattered, even with header=None I still got issues. I'm still not clear why the header is so important when we are assigning our own values to the columns for purposes of the dataframe, but its working now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: from where `27-sep` come in your expected output? and some emails not included in the output `uiop@fmail.com`

Comment: deadshot - the 27-sep comes in from my datetime stamp if I run it today - also the uiop@fmail.com is filtered out by line 31 - it filters out any emails addresses with less than 30 emails (uiop only has 11)

Comment: Trenton I am certainly interested - I've used Panda's once before but I know nothing about it. I initially didnt use it because I need this script to be able generate the applicable rows and columns on its own without my input, and I assumed panda required me to tailor-make the dataframe to fit/append data where I need it.

If it can do what I need it to, please show me how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I'd load the data with [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html?highlight=rename#pandas.DataFrame.rename) some columns

  - Renaming the columns in `working`, is dependent upon the column index, since `working.csv` has no column headers.

    - When the `working` dataframe is created, look at the dataframe to verify the correct columns have been loaded, and the correct column index is being used for renaming.
  - The `date` column of `arch` should really be `email`, because headers identify what's below them, not the other column headers.
  - Once the column name has been changed in `archive.csv`, then rename won't be required any longer.
- [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) on the `email` column.

  - Since both dataframes have a column renamed with `email`, the merged result will only have one `email` column.
  - If the merge occurs on two different column names, then the result will have two columns containing email addresses.
  - [pandas: Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)
- As long as the columns in the files are consistent, this should work without modification

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# get the date string
datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d-%b')

# read archive
arch = pd.read_csv('archive.csv')

# rename columns
arch.rename(columns={'date': 'email'}, inplace=True)

# read working, but only the two columns that are needed
working = pd.read_csv('working.csv', header=None, usecols=[1, 3])

# rename columns
working.rename(columns={1: 'email', 3: datestring}, inplace=True)

# only emails greater than 30 or already in arch
working = working[(working[datestring] > 30) | (working.email.isin(arch.email))]

# merge
arch_updated = pd.merge(arch, working, on='email', how='outer').fillna(0)

# save to csv
arch_updated.to_csv('archive.csv', index=False)

# display(arch_updated)
          email  01-sep  27-Aug
 asdf@email.com   154.0    31.0
 fsda@email.com   128.0    19.0
 qwer@gmail.com    77.0    92.0
 ffff@xmail.com    63.0     0.0
 zxcv@email.com     0.0   117.0
```

Comment: I should clarify that the "working.csv" contains a bunch of other data as well; I filter that out with other parts of the script. I've produced a new CSV to replace "working.csv" which contains two columns: [0]email, [1]count; I've modified your solution to reflect that and have had varying degrees of success. I will post it above and check back later

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem is you have two sets of data. Both have the data stored with a "key" entry (the emails) and additional piece of data that you want condensed down to one storage. Identifying that there is a similar "key" for both of these sets of data simplifies this greatly.

Imagine each key as being the name of a bucket. Each bucket needs two pieces of info, one piece from one csv and the other piece from the other csv.

Now, I must take a small detour to explain a dictionary in python. Here is a definition stolen from  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp#:%7E:text=Previous%20Next%20%E2%9D%AF-,Dictionary,they%20have%20keys%20and%20values.)

> A dictionary is a collection which is unordered, changeable and indexed.

A collection is a container like a list that holds data. Unordered and indexed means that the dictionary is not accessible like a list where the data is accessible by the index. In this case, the dictionary is accessed using keys, which can be anything like a string or a number (technically the key must be hashable, but thats too indepth). And finally changeable means that the dictionary can actually have its the stored data changed (once again, oversimplified).

Example:

```
dictionary = dict()
key = "Something like a string or a number!"
dictionary[key] = "any kind of value can be stored here! Even lists and other dictionaries!"
print(dictionary[key])  # Would print the above string
```

Here is the structure that I suggest you use instead of most of your lists:

```
dictionary[email] = [item1, item2]
```

This way, you can avoid using multiple lists and massively simplifying your code. If you are still iffy on the usage of dictionaries, there are a lot of articles and videos on the usage of them. Good luck!